# How to find the derivative of matrix conjugation for unitary matrices at a point where the matrices commute?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $\text{SU}(2)$ denote the special group of $2 \times 2$ unitary matrices, that is, unitary matrices with determinant $1$.

Define $f : \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2) \to \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2)$ by

$$f(A, B) = (BAB^{-1}, B)$$

Let $A, B \in \text{SU}(2)$ be such that $A$ and $B$ commute.Find $\mathrm{d}f_{(A, B)}$.

Here's what I have so far (I'm pretty sure the solution is valid, but would like a second opinion / critiques):

By definition, $\mathrm{d}f_{(A, B)}$ is the map taking $(C, D)$ to
$$
    \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f((A, B) + t(C, D)) - f(A, B)}{t}.
$$
Then
$$
    (B + tD)(A + tC)(B + tD)^{-1} = (B + tD)(A + tC)(B^* + tD^*) = A + tBAD^* + tBCB^* + t^2 BCD^* + tDAB^* + t^2 DAD^* + t^2 DCB^* + t^3 DCD^*
$$
where the first equality comes from the fact that the matrices are unitary.
So the numerator in the limit is $(tBAD^* + tBCB^* + t^2 BCD^* + tDAB^* + t^2 DAD^* + t^2 DCB^* + t^3 DCD^*, tD)$ and after dividing this by $t$ we get
$$
    df_{(A, B)}(C, D) = \lim_{t\to 0} (BAD^* + BCB^* + t BCD^* + DAB^* + t DAD^* + t DCB^* + t^2 DCD^*, D) = (BAD^* + BCB^* + DAB^*, D)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality is wrong; $B^{-1}=B^*$ and $D^{-1}=D^*$ don't imply $(B+tD)^{-1}=B^*+tD^*$. You need to expand the inverse in powers of $t$:

\begin{align}
(B+tD)^{-1}&=\left(B\left(1+tB^{-1}D\right)\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(1+tB^{-1}D\right)^{-1}B^{-1}\\
&=\left(1-tB^{-1}D+O\left(t^2\right)\right)B^{-1}\\
&=B^*-tB^*DB^*+O\left(t^2\right)\;.
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
(B + tD)(A + tC)(B + tD)^{-1}&=(B + tD)(A + tC)(B^*-tB^*DB^*)+O\left(t^2\right)\\
&=BAB^*+t(DAB^*+BCB^*-BAB^*DB^*)+O\left(t^2\right)\\
&=BAB^*+t(DAB^*+BCB^*-ADB^*)+O\left(t^2\right)\\
&=BAB^*+t(DA+BC-AD)B^*+O\left(t^2\right)\;,
\end{align}

where the penultimate step uses the fact that $A$ and $B$ commute. Thus, the differential is $((DA+BC-AD)B^*,D)$.

Comment: Can you explain the third equality of the first set of equations (where $O(t^2)$ first appears)?

Comment: @JohnDoe: This is analogous to $\frac1{1+x}=1-x+O\left(x^2\right)$. To see that it works out for matrices, multiply out: $\left(1+tB^{-1}D\right)\left(1-tB^{-1}D\right)= 1+tB^{-1}D-tB^{-1}D+O\left(t^2\right)=1+O\left(t^2\right)$. Since the product is right up to $O\left(t^2\right)$ and adding something to the inverse produces a term of the same order in the product, it follows that the inverse is right up to $O\left(t^2\right)$.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without $O$ notation? It still seems pretty hand wavy to me :(

Comment: @JohnDoe: What's hand-wavy about big-$O$ notation? It's quite well-defined: the difference is bounded by a constant multiple of the argument. I didn't apply it rigorously throughout this proof sketch, but that's not the fault of the big-$O$ notation; you can fill in the details. The most hand-wavy part was the one with the expansion of the inverse, and I think I made that rigorous in the above comment? Of course you can carry along all the terms all the time and then only argue that they don't contribute in the end, but I don't see how that's more rigorous than making the argument earlier on.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, thank you.